# How to dynamically pass azure pipeline variable name and load it's value in powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to load pipeline variables into my powershell script. The following works, but the variable is hardcoded which does not support my use-case:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
    echo "The following output: $env:VARIABLE1"
```

Instead I would like to dynamically pass VARIABLE1. So something like this (which does not work):

```
parameters:
- name: variableName
  type: string
  default: VARIABLE1

steps:
- powershell: |
    echo "The following output: $env:${{ parameters.variableName }}"
```

One way I thought of doing this is to save the entire script, run a find and replace on it and set the variables that way before executing. However, it seems to me like there should be a better way.

Some additional context for the problem: I'm running into a problem where my parameters are resolved at compile-time, and the variables I need in this template are not yet available when that happens. So I thought by passing the variable name, I could load it into the script when it is executed, circumventing my problem.

Answer (score -2):

Think about what the statement `$env:${{ parameters.variableName }}"` does. You're interpolating the *value* of the `variableName` parameter, then trying to treat it as an environment variable by referencing it as `$env:`. That doesn't make any sense. You're already injecting the value into the script. You can map parameters into environment variables with an `env` block on your `powershell` step.

```
steps:
- powershell: |
    echo "The following output: $env:FOO"
  env:
    FOO: ${{ parameters.variableName }}
```

Comment: That brings me one step further, but doesn't solve my issue unfortunately: the value in parameters.variableName is the name of another variable. Your solution prints the contents of parameters.variableName, but not the underlaying value. E.g. variableName contains a 'ThisVariableIsTrue', with value 'True'. If that's the case I would like to print 'True'.